# jBPM : How to copy an element from an array to another process variable

Tags: jbpm

I have a jBPM processs level variable that contains an array of objects. I need to copy an element of this array into another process variable. If java representation is as below,

```
public class ClassA { 
  ClassB blist[]; 
};

public class ClassB {... }
```

I want to copy `blist[5]` to another process variable of type ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, but can someone confirm this is the optimal way to to do it in jBPM. 
- Add an Activity object in the jBPM-BusinessCentral's Business Process diagram
- Set the Activity type to of type Script. 
- In the Script's "Implementation/Execution" section select Java and wrote the following code snippet,

```
System.out.println("Inside the script...");
Object glbinvitem = kcontext.getVariable("glb_invitem");
if ( glbinvitem != null) { 
 ....
}
else {
 ...
}
```

- In the above snippet, "glb_invitem" is the name of the global variable in the business process

Comment: Missed the point that once you have access to global variable(s), one should be able to write java code to manipulate it and then reset it back into the process by using the setVariable(String name, Object objectvalue ) method on the kcontext object. (assuming that setVariable() is a threadsafe method).

Comment: If you really want to have the same variable value in all process instances of the same process definition you need to use global variables.
`kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("glb_invitem", "new value");` and `kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().getGlobal("glb_invitem");`